# How to do image subtraction in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I need to do the image subtraction using two images in objective-C. Are there any framework in objective-C to do that?. How can I accomplish my task. Thanks

Comment: What do you exactly mean by image subtraction?

Comment: just need to subtract the pixels values from two images

Answer (score 1):

You are either looking for [image masks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHBCGB) or [blending](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBDCFBH) mode. They are both available in Core Graphics.